# ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method - Jmeter PreProcessor

Tags: groovy, jmeter, beanshell, jsr223

Need help figuring out an issue with Jmeter BeanShell PreProcessor, I am using below code to grab variable data and pass as next POST request but its failing, although I can see that all variables are being captured correctly.

Please help identify what is causing the issue

```
int keys = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("getkeys_matchNr"));
StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
requestBuilder.append("[");
for (int i = 1; i <= keys; i++) {
    requestBuilder.append(vars.get("getkeys_" + i));
    if (i != keys) {
        requestBuilder.append(",");
    }
}
requestBuilder.append("]");
sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(requestBuilder.toString());
```

getting below error:

2023-11-01 12:51:12,275 ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``int keys = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("getkeys_ . . . '' : Attempt to resolve method: toString() on undefined variable or class name: out

try setValue to different string - "sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(out.toString(0));" but did not work either

Answer (score 0):

I fail to see any declaration of `out` object in your code, most probably it's a copy-paste issue, try replacing `out` with `requestBuilder` and the issue will go away.

Also using Beanshell is a some form of a performance anti-pattern, [since JMeter 3.1 you should be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting.

Example code:

```
def requestBuilder = []
1.upto(vars.get('getkeys_matchNr') as int, { index ->
    requestBuilder.add(vars.get('getkeys_' + index))
})

def payload = new org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.util.HTTPArgument('', new groovy.json.JsonBuilder(requestBuilder).toPrettyString(), '')
def arguments = sampler.getArguments()
arguments.addArgument(payload)
sampler.setArguments(arguments)
```

More information:

- [Apache Groovy: Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/processing-json.html)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: Thanks Dmitri for getting back my orginal request had "requestBuilder" already and was failing.

Comment: now I switched to groovy using below code, is works but its not putting data on the BODY am I doing something wrong?

import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

int startIndex = 1
int endIndex = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("keys_ matchNr"));  

def variableList = []

for (int i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++) {
    def variableName = "keys_" + i
    def variableValue = vars.get(variableName)
    variableList.add(variableValue)
}


def jsonBuilder = new JsonBuilder(variableList)
def jsonArray = jsonBuilder.toPrettyString()

return jsonArray